# Capture Angular API response from service to component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular 12 application, I am making an API call in the service file and want to capture the response of the API in my component.
But since the API response is async, the console below always returns undefined. I have tried async await as well. Here is what I have tried:

INSIDE SERVICE:

```
public checkEmail(emailToVerify: any) {
    this.myService.emailValidate({ email: emailToVerify }).subscribe({
      next: (data: { result: any) => {
        console.log('updateEmail-res', data);
        return data;
      },
      error: (err: any) => {
        console.log('updateEmail-err', err);
      }
    });
  }
```

INSIDE COMPONENT:

```
this.apiResponse = await this.myService.checkEmail(customerEmail);
 console.log("this.apiResponse", this.apiResponse)
```

Comment: There is a robust guide on this topic: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Your service doesn't return anything. Return in subscribe doesn't  matter. The subscription should be within the component and there you assign the data within the subscription to the components field.

Answer (score 0):

In Component

```
validateEmail = async () => {
    const params = {
      emailAddress: 'test@gmail.com',
    };
    const apiResponse: boolean = await this.emailService.validateEmail(params);
    console.log(`apiResponse===`, apiResponse);
  };
```

In Service

```
export class EmailService {
  constructor() {}

  validateEmail = async (params: {
    emailAddress: string;
  }): Promise<boolean> => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const isValid = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(
        params.emailAddress
      );

      resolve(isValid);
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The checkemail method does nothing. If you already have emailValidate, why put it in another method?
just one emailValidate instead of checkEmail

```
this.apiResponse = await this.myService.emailValidate({ email: customerEmail});
 console.log("this.apiResponse", this.apiResponse)
```

o
in you component:

```
this.myService.emailValidate({ email: customerEmail}).subscribe({
          next: (data: { result: any) => {
            console.log('updateEmail-res', data);
             this.apiResponse = data;
          },
          error: (err: any) => {
            console.log('updateEmail-err', err);
          }
        });
```